# python security update installation on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python security updates are source only updates. There is no windows installer.
For instance the page for [python 3.6.12](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3612/) states:

> Security fix releases are produced periodically as needed and are source-only releases; binary installers are not provided.

Coud someone explain how I can update/patch a python installation done by the windows installer so that latest python security fixes are applied:
eg going from python 3.6.6 to python 3.6.12

Or if not possible how to install from python source code directly.

Thx for the help.

Comment: I really like Python and its documentation, but it's difficult to find anything about this :-( Somewhere it mentions "_if you want to install from source, see the [general download page](http://www.python.org/download/)_", but that download page doesn't say anything about building from source...

Comment: It does seem to be explained in the Python Developer's Guide - [Getting Started](https://devguide.python.org/setup/)

Comment: The developer's guide explain how to build from source but not how to install once built :-( It is a shame python community does not take security updates as seriously as "features" updates.

Comment: I totally agree, and I don't understand why they can't create a full release for security updates as well. I guess a *very* small part of the users will take the effort to completely built CPython from source to fix a security issue in a third-party application. So it does not really solve the security issues then :-(  I'm still hoping we missed something and there is an easier way...

Comment: You can find the Azure Pipelines definitions they use for building MSIs over at https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/.azure-pipelines/windows-release if that helps...

Comment: Take a look at `Tools/msi` and more specifically the build bats in there. Installers are outputted in subdirectories of the PCbuild directory. EDIT: If you are compiling from source, you may as well compile straight off the 3.6 branch rather than bothering with the release.

Comment: To follow this up, @zooma is really the person you need to ask about all this stuff (and maybe create an bug-tracker issue to add this to the devguide?)

Comment: Hello who is zooma? the link does not work.

Comment: Sorry, [zooba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/891/zooba) (not zooma) is the alias of Steve Dower who is responsible for the Windows CPython releases and more generally helping with Python-Windows problems on bpo.

Comment: Why not just install 3.8.5 (i.e., the newest)?

Comment: Do you want to update python.

Comment: Hello. About installing 3.8.5 or any newer release. This is just avoiding the issue for a short while as 3.8.xxx will also go into security updates only sooner or later. Changing the python release is a risk as I deploy a python "product" and just want to ensure it uses latest security updates on the targeted python release (for which I also built some custom dlls/pyd, another reason for not taking a different "features" release).

Comment: @MinionJim Huh? I simply asked why they don't do it, to make sure they are indeed avoiding it for such real reasons. Some people avoid things for bad reasons, so please don't treat this like some alien concept.

Comment: @superbrain than if 3.8.12 appear, how to upgrade 3.8.5 to 3.8.12? The question remains.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To install security patches after the last full bugfix release, you must build Python from source:

### Compile the Binaries

1. Install [`Visual Studio 2019 Community`](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/) and select:

- the **Python development** workload, and
- the **Python native development tools** (this is under `Optional`, but is necessary in order to build python from source)

  [image: Python development workload and native development tools]

2. Download the python source code and unzip it.
3. Navigate to the folder and install required external dependencies by running `PCbuild\get_externals.bat`
4. Build the debug (`python_d.exe`) and release (`python.exe`) binaries

```
> PCbuild\build.bat -p x64 -c Debug
> PCbuild\build.bat -p x64 -c Release
```

you can also build the Profile Guided Optimization (`pgo`) binary

```
> PCbuild\build.bat -p x64 --pgo
```

The binaries on `python.org` are run through PGO by default, so a `--pgo` binary will be faster than a `-c Release` binary. The debug binary is necessary for adding breakpoints and debugging your code.

All built binaries are placed in `PCbuild\amd64`.

#### Build the Installer

The instructions for building an installer are in `Tools\msi\README.txt`.

1. Download the extra build dependencies by running `Tools\msi\get_externals.bat`

> **NOTE:** *This is done in addition to running `PCbuild/get_externals.bat`.*
>
> *It installs additional binaries to `externals\windows-installer` that are
> needed for making installers. Specifically,*
>
> - **WiX** (`wix.exe`), *which is a toolset that lets developers create installers for Windows Installer, the Windows installation
>   engine.*
> - **HTML Help** (`htmlhelp`), *which is for building documentation.*

2. Turn on `.NET Framework 3.5 Features` under `Turn Windows features on or off`

   [image: .NET Framework 3.5 Features]

> **NOTE:** *This is required by WiX.*

3. Build the installer by running

```
> .\Tools\msi\buildrelease.bat -x64
```

**NOTE:** Be sure the following environment variables are properly set or left blank so the script can set them:

```
PYTHON=<path to python.exe>
SPHINXBUILD=<path to sphinx-build.exe>
```

The installer will be placed in `PCbuild\amd64\en-us`. It is a single `.exe` (the installer entry point). The folder will also have a number of additional CAB and MSI files. Each MSI contains the logic required to install a component or feature of Python, but these should not be run directly.

Specify `--pack` to build an installer that does not require all MSIs to be available alongside. This takes longer, but is easier to share.

Comment: Many thanks for the solution. It takes a long time but it is important to update our software. I upgraded to Python 3.10.13. If in the future we have 3.10.17. Do I need to do these steps for each new update (3.10.14, 3.10.15, 3.10.16, 3.10.17)? Do you think the last one already has all the previous bugfixes?

Comment: You're very welcome! Yes, bugfixes are generally cumulative (i.e. 3.10.17 has all the fixes of its predecessors). This is covered in the [Developer's Guide](https://devguide.python.org/developer-workflow/development-cycle/#maintenance-branches), but it is very rare (if ever) that compatibility is broken between sibling micro releases (e.g. `3.5.1` and `3.5.2`).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to install python of version 3.6.13 using [conda](https://www.anaconda.com/) 
Just install python 3.6 in separate invironment:

```
conda create -n myenvironment python=3.6
conda activate myenvironment
python --vesion
```

Or point out specific version:

```
conda create -n myenvironment python=3.6.13
```

Check all available versions:

```
conda search python
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you just don't install a newer version as you're on windows (3.8), but if you really have to do it from source, this link should help you.

https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/other/python/0596001886_pythonian-chp-2-sect-1.html

Disclaimer: I've not tested it, but the process should work

Comment: I'm getting down votes on this, but i'm actually failing to understand why is that so. Could someone please take a minute to tell that, so that i can correct if there's something wrong.

Comment: My personal issue mainly that the quality and age of the given link is not wonderful. However, I guess it is not really fair to hold you to account for what you have linked so have un-down voted.

Comment: Reason why this is wrong is many people are restricted to which versions of Python they can use. Maybe it's the OS of the servers they're using (CentOS 7 only permits Python 2.7, 3.4, or 3.6 and good luck telling a SysAdmin that a mission critical server needs an upgrade because you want a new version of Python), or maybe you're integrating with software that uses Python plugins built using a specific version. If you need to develop for those systems, you need to use the correct versions